# load a page with jQuery.ajax, how is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

why in this code after click not displaying(or not load) mysite.html?

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
      $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){                
            $(".results").append(html);
            $(this).hide().show();
            //$.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
            }
        });
        //.hide().show("slow")
    });
});
```

Comment: What is URL? If it is not the same origin, it will not load

Comment: Could be any of a hundred different reasons. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".results").load('mysite.html');
```

Of course `mysite.html` must be in the same folder as the script, or you can use full url (*always restricted to same origin policy*) 'http://www.yoursite.com/mysite.html'

You can also do it with *.ajax* method, the *.load* way just make it simple.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mysite.html", //or full url http://...
  success: function(data){
    $('.results').html(data);
  }
});
```

In `.load` method you can set a callback function too:

```
$(".results").load('mysite.html', myCallback);
```

You should take a look at *jQuery API*, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I can not do that with $.ajax()?

Comment: no. with ajax you have to use a server side script the handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `.load()` plugin..