# How to load a particular div with other JSP page using JQuery.Ajax

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to load Jsp Page in Div empProfTable using JqueryAjax. and Ihve done like this, im not whether its a right way or not to do so. Please Help

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GenerateID.jsp",
    type: 'post',
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#empProfTable").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/admin/AddStaff/addempdetail.jsp?Education=1&empid=" + id);
 }
```

And here is my jsp page

```
 <% if(request.getParameter("Education")!=null)
{
 %>
<div id="EduQual" style="margin-top: 50px;" >
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr bgcolor="#7ce9ff">
        <td width="12%"><strong>Empcode</strong></td>
        <td width="10%"><strong>Education</strong></td>

    </tr></table>
<% } %>
```

Im not getting any error either. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not the right way, what is the first url for?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are trying to load a div using load() method when ajax call to GenerateID.jsp return success. is that you need to do? But in the ajax call, you are using POST but i Cant see any variables posted to the GenerateID.jsp page. If you simply want to load the content of empProfTable div, first check that the url exists in your site and do the load() call alone. For your reference [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/%E2%80%8E), [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763596/load-a-page-with-jquery-ajax-how-is-it?rq=1)